# Widgets not appearing [different case]

Tags: python, tkinter

This is what I tried:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import TOP,BOTTOM,LEFT,RIGHT
_master=''
class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        global _master
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._master=self
    def stay(self):
        self._master.mainloop()
class button():
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        global _master
        if 'image' in kwargs:
            self._image=tk.PhotoImage(file=kwargs['image'])
            self._button=tk.Button(_master,image=_image)
            if 'x' in kwargs and 'y' in kwargs:
                self._button.place(x=kwargs['x'],y=kwargs['y'])
            elif 'x' in kwargs:
                self._button.place(x=kwargs['x'])
            elif 'y' in kwargs:
                self._button.place(y=kwargs['y'])
            elif 'side' in kwargs:
                self._button.place(side=kwargs['side'])
            else:
                self._button.place()
        if 'text' in kwargs:
            self._text=kwargs[text]
            self._button=tk.Button(_master,text=_text)
            if 'x' in kwargs and 'y' in kwargs:
                _button.place(x=kwargs['x'],y=kwargs['y'])
            elif 'x' in kwargs:
                _button.place(x=kwargs['x'])
            elif 'y' in kwargs:
                _button.place(y=kwargs['y'])
            elif 'side' in kwargs:
                _button.place(side=kwargs['side'])
            else:
                _button.place()
            
            
class text():
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            global _master
            self.text=kwargs['text']
            self._label=tk.Label(kwargs['win'],text=text)
            if 'x' in kwargs and 'y' in kwargs:
                self._label.place(x=kwargs['x'],y=kwargs['y'])
            elif 'x' in kwargs:
                self._label.place(x=kwargs['x'])
            elif 'y' in kwargs:
                self._label.place(y=kwargs['y'])
            elif 'side' in kwargs:
                self._label.place(side=kwargs['side'])
            else:
                self._label.place()
                
win=GUI()
text(win=win,text='Hey')

win.stay()
```

But it doesn't work.
It doesn't show up.
Without any errors, it just shows blank tk window.
I am trying to make a GUI library for myself (or maybe even for public)
How can I fix this?
Also why is this happening?

Comment: Note that calling `place()` without option will not *place* the widget.  At least specify `x` or `y` option, better both.  Also `self._label=tk.Label(kwargs['win'],text=text)` should be `self._label=tk.Label(kwargs['win'],text=self.text)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thanks acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70390899/widgets-not-appearing-different-case#comment124429330_70390899)

> Note that calling `place()` without option will not place the widget.
> At least specify `x` or `y` option, better both. Also
> `self._label=tk.Label(kwargs['win'],text=text)` should be
> `self._label=tk.Label(kwargs['win'],text=self.text)` instead.